# How do i undo a cypher code for any words entered?

Tags: python

I have the following caesar code function: I want to be able to undo the cyphering and return the original word, what i have here works for the word "hello" it cyphers the word as "xvdei", and decyphers it as "hello". However it will not work for any other words i put, i want to know how i can go about to edit this out so that any word i put will decypher back into the original word.So like if i put xvdei i will get back "hello" or if i put in hijklm and shift it by 7 i will get back "aaaaaa"

```
alphabet=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

def decypher(text,shift):  
    # initialize ciphertext as blank string
    dtext = ""

# loop through the length of the plaintext
    for i in range(len(text)):        
    # get the ith letter from the plaintext
        l = text[i]
    # find the number position of the ith letter
        n_alphabet = alphabet.index(l)

    # find the number position of the cipher by adding the shift

        c_num = (n_alphabet + shift ) % len(alphabet) - 6 - i

    # find the cipher letter for the cipher number you computed
        c_letter = alphabet[c_num] 
    # add the cipher letter to the ciphertext
        dtext = dtext + c_letter 

# return the computed ciphertext
    return dtext
```

I need to decypher what this function gives me to the original word:

```
def caesar(plaintext,shift):  
# initialize ciphertext as blank string
    ciphertext = ""

# loop through the length of the plaintext
    for i in range(len(plaintext)):        
    # get the ith letter from the plaintext
        letter = plaintext[i]
    # find the number position of the ith letter
        num_in_alphabet = alphabet.index(letter)

    # find the number position of the cipher by adding the shift 
        cipher_num = (num_in_alphabet + shift + i) % len(alphabet) 
    # find the cipher letter for the cipher number you computed
        cipher_letter = alphabet[cipher_num] 
    # add the cipher letter to the ciphertext
        ciphertext = ciphertext + cipher_letter 

# return the computed ciphertext
    return ciphertext
```

Comment: What have you tried, and why isn't it working?

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: If "hello" encodes to "xvdei", then you're not implementing a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).  Multiple copies of the same letter should encode to the same thing.

Comment: i have tried the following line of code:   c_num = (n_alphabet + shift ) % len(alphabet) - 6 - i, however that only gives me hello, every other letter returns incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Reversing the cypher only needs to continue shifting up to the point where it reaches a complete cycle (i.e. by the rest of the letters):

```
def decypher(text,shift): return cypher(text,len(alphabet)-shift)
```

also, in your code:

```
cipher_num = (num_in_alphabet + shift + i) % len(alphabet)
```

should be

```
cipher_num = (num_in_alphabet + shift) % len(alphabet)
```

Comment: alright let me try this. i have it working for the word hello but i feel it's because i put in all the values correct and only works on that word. Sorry should have mentioned, the function i want to look at is decypher, the other function cyphers the word and decypher is to bring it back to the original word.

Comment: `cypher()` has a bug (or is not a caesar's cypher).  If you do intend to implement  caesar's cypher, then `decypher()` becomes trivial once you have `cypher()` worked out.

Comment: the function caesar works as intended, i have entered some words in and it does it correctly. I know that to decypher it's just working backwards, however i only have it working with one word because i entered the values to get this one word back but i'm unsure how i could get back any word i put in.

Comment: Then your cypher() function is not an actual caesar's cypher.  A compliant caesar's cypher("hello",2) would return "jgnnq".  Then, cypher("jgnnq",24) or decypher("jgnnq",2) would return "hello".  We would need you to keep your cypher function in the question in order to reverse engineer the custom encryption that you implemented.

Comment: @AlexDeJesus As I mentioned, if "hello" encodes to "xvdei", then it's not working as intended (or what you intend is not actually a Caesar's cipher).

Comment: oh im sorry it is, the problem is that it shifts the letter by the shift key so if the word is hello it shifts it by 16 if 16 is the shift key, but also shifts it by the position of the letter, so thats why i have (+ i) cause i need it to also shift by the position, which is why "hello", 16 becomes xvdei, h + 16 + i which is o, and e + 16 + 1(since its position 1) and so forth. i will add the other part.